# Linux Boost Compile Error

Tags: linux, boost

When i compile code . I have add -pthread.It output Error.

platform : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.3 (Santiago)

Kernel:Linux localhost 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jun 13 18:24:36 EDT 2012 x86_64 x86_64 
x86_64 GNU/Linux

gcc version: 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC)

boost: 1.48

```
1)/usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/platform.hpp:67:9: error: #error "Sorry, no boost threads are available for this platform."
2)/usr/local/include/boost/config/requires_threads.hpp:47:5: error: #error "Compiler threading support is not turned on. Please set the correct command line options for threading: -pthread (Linux), -pthreads (Solaris) or -mthreads (Mingw32)"
```

If you have any good ideas I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: And what platform are you on?

Comment: please provide more information, like what OS, compiler, boost version you are using and how exactly you are compiling. other than that the error message text is actually quite descriptive...

Comment: And have you tried adding -pthread to your build?

Comment: Yes. added -pthread.Still Error!

Comment: Don't build Boost yourself.  Install it using your distro's package manager (`yum` in your case), either from the official repos or from some third-party repos if you need a newer version.